# An exception throwed when I'm trying to download source code from SVN

Tags: svn, proxy, tortoisesvn, jaspersoft-studio

I have found the manual on official Jasperreport comunity website, how to download source code of Jaspersoft Studio from SVN. But when I am trying connect to `http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jaspersoftstudio` with username and password `anonsvn`, like they sad, I get this error:

I am trying to download the source code of Jaspersoft Studio from SVN  with username and password "anonsvn". I get everytime this error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn/repos/jaspersoftstudio': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://code.jaspersoft.com)
```

The developers's comment for this error is:

```
This could have the following meaning(s):
- the folder specified in the repository URL does not exist on the host
- your proxy does not allow the svn command you have invoked
```

I have tried other SVN clients, but they are throwing similar error.

How can I fix this please or where can I download source code else?
Thanks

Comment: I tried opening the url in a browser with your credentials, which worked instantly. So this might be connected to a proxy problem. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: It's working in browser normally, but you need SVN client to download project...and in every SVN client I have tried it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proxy did not allow the svn command I have invoked